# Cloudfront with 2 origins (different buckets) and both host root of bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CDN and 2 buckets

- one bucket is using the default behaviour so `img.png` is accessible via CDN URL: `cdn.com/img.png`
- one bucket is using the `/path` behaviour so everything in the CDN routed to /path should go to this bucket. It works when i put this in the bucket: `path/test.png`. I can visit `cdn.com/path/test.png`.

What I want is to put `test.png` in the root of my bucket without the prefix of `path/`. Is this possible (without the use of lambda@edge)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite the path, you have to use lambda@edge.

If you are ok with 301 redirection, you can try enabling static website hosting on S3 bucket and [use the following redirection rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html#advanced-conditional-redirects):

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>path/</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith/>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```